# Symfony2 ParameterNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I followed the steps to install FOSUserBundle and ([NmnMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/netmeansnet/NmnMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)
, to be able to have multiple user classes).

After finishing the steps of installing NmnMultiUserBundle and trying to get the new schema (doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql) I got the following exception from the console:

`[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
The service "nmn_user.manager.user_discriminator" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "nmn_user_discriminator_parameters".`

I thought it was the cache, so did a `cache:clear` but it also gave me the exception.

Does anybody know the reason for that?

Comment: see https://github.com/netmeansnet/NmnMultiUserBundle/issues/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one step of the bundle installation, see https://github.com/netmeansnet/NmnMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#6-configure-parameters-for-userdiscriminator

Comment: I did that step, my config.yml is here: http://pastebin.com/4frM6w9f
('Kozold' is the company)

Comment: Try to put this in your app/config/config.yml